# combine two dataframes with same index (unordered)

Tags: python, pandas

I don't know why this is confusing me so much.  I am trying to combine two dataframes, and both share the same index (although as a note, they may not be in the same order).

```
df1 = |firstrow  10|
      |secondrow 15|

df2 = |secondrow  115|
      |firstrow  1000|
```

and I want the resulting dataframe to be:

```
result = |firstrow  10  1000|
         |secondrow 15   115|
```

I have tried doing this:

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2, on="INDEXNAME"), but it throws a KeyError on INDEXNAME
```

thanks!

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: Figured it out - df1.join(df2).  Automatically uses the index

Comment: You can also use `pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)` to achieve the same thing as `pd.join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) (by default outer join):

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

And if need inner join:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, join='inner')
```

Or [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) (by default `inner` join) with parameters `left_index` and `right_index`:

```
df = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Sample:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':[10,15]}, index=['firstrow','secondrow'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'b':[115,1000]}, index=['secondrow','firstrow'])
print (df1)
            a
firstrow   10
secondrow  15

print (df2)
              b
secondrow   115
firstrow   1000

print (pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1))
            a     b
secondrow  15   115
firstrow   10  1000

print (pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True))
            a     b
secondrow  15   115
firstrow   10  1000
```